# creation of !ENTITY definition

Tags: python, xml, lxml

With python lxml how can I create a !ENTITY definition, Note I want to create rather than parse.

That is I want to create some xml that has an include of another file, hence the need for an !ENTITY definition

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create the doctype declaration, with the internal subset that has the ENTITY declaration, as a string and pass that when you serialize (with tostring() or write()).

Example...

```py
from lxml import etree

doctype = """<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY ent SYSTEM "another_doc.xml">
]>"""

doc = etree.Element("doc")
ent = etree.Entity("ent")
doc.append(ent)

print(etree.tostring(doc, doctype=doctype).decode())
```

prints...

```xml
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY ent SYSTEM "another_doc.xml">
]>
<doc>&ent;</doc>
```

Comment: How do you specify the & and ; in a SubElement?
i.e. where I wish to use the include

Comment: @KeithSloan - You don't; you create the entity reference with `etree.Entity("ent")` and the `&` and `;` are added automatically when it's serialized. How/where you add the created the entity may differ, but you haven't added any code to your question so it's hard for me to understand exactly what you're asking.