# Creation of GDML include using python and lxml

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml, xml-entities

According to the GDML manual I can include another file as follows
[image]

How can I create/add the &materials; to the  element using python and lxml?

Comment: The answer to *How can I create/add the &materials;...* is here already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418151/407651.

Comment: Duplicate of [creation of !ENTITY definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415435/creation-of-entity-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`etree.Entity`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#Entity)...

```py
from lxml import etree

docString = '<!DOCTYPE gdml [\n<!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materials.xml">\n]>'

NS = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
location_attribute = f"{{{NS}}}noNameSpaceSchemaLocation"
gdml = etree.Element("gdml",
                     attrib={location_attribute:
                             "blahblahblah/gdml.xsd"})

ent_ref = etree.Entity("materials")

gdml.append(ent_ref)

print(etree.tostring(gdml, doctype=docString).decode())
```

prints...

```xml
<!DOCTYPE gdml [
<!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materials.xml">
]>
<gdml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="blahblahblah/gdml.xsd">&materials;</gdml>
```

Comment: Perhaps I was not CLEAR enough. 

I want to know how to create the &materials;

Comment: @KeithSloan - You were clear. My example does create the entity ref `&defines;`. Maybe my answer is not clear enough? I'll add a couple of line breaks so you can see the entity reference without scrolling. Maybe that will make it more clear. I'll also change `defines` to `materials` to also improve clarity. (I used the example entity declarations from one of your other questions and reduced it.)

Comment: Okay file now looks like 
<!DOCTYPE gdml [
<!ENTITY define SYSTEM "define.xml">
<!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materials.xml">
<!ENTITY solids SYSTEM "fred4-solids.xml">
<!ENTITY structure SYSTEM "fred4-structure.xml">
<!ENTITY setup SYSTEM "setup.xml">
]>
<gdml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app/releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd">
  &define;
&materials;
&solids;
&structure;
<setup name="Default" version="1.0">
    <world ref="world0x55d123cff820"/>
  </setup>
</gdml>

Comment: But I have a problem when I try and import, it does not seem to be expanding the entities despite the code being
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=True)
       root = etree.parse(filename, parser=parser)

Comment: @KeithSloan: The answer does explain how to create `&materials;`. If you have follow-up issues, please ask a new question. Also, it is very hard to read XML markup and code in comments.

Comment: "Also, it is very hard to read XML markup and code in comments" Agreed that is why I also added code to initial query but it says will not be seen until a moderator okays it